# Rails filter by SQL search in different model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, filtering

In my Photos view there is an option to search using a text_field. I wanted to add an option to "search" by clicking on predefined tags. Perhaps a `search` is not the best way to do this.

This is the method for search in my model:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name or description or tag.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

I'm not sure that I am calling this correctly either... But these are the links I create in the index view for photos:

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, :search => tag.name, :class => "tag" %>
<% end %>
```

`Tags` are not in the photo table, but have HABTM relation with photos. I can normally call them though simply with @photo.tags.name or something similiar. 
Anyway, when I click a tag it spits back a `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: tag.name: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "photos" WHERE (name or description or tag.name LIKE '%landscape%')`. Any thoughts? Perhaps there is a better way to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find by a field that is in the tags table you have to make a join with it. To make it change your search method to this:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    joins(:tags).where('name or description or tags.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! That works, but I have to remove `name or description` as they are photo fields, not tag fields. Do I need to create a separate method for tag searches, or can I specify that `tags.name` is in the `tags` table, while `name or description` are in the photos table?

Comment: You can do it event if those fields are in differents tables, but just to be sure you can make this `joins(:tags).where('photos.name or photos.description or tags.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")`

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the trick. Interestingly, there is one particular photo now that shows up 5x times in the results for any search! Really weird. I'll try to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Coming with your own solution to common problems is a great way to learn, however, I'd recommend that you delegate the tags job to a specialized gem like: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on, so you can keep focused on your business.

Also, using a relational model to save tags is somewhat overkill: a comma-separated list of tags should be enough for most cases.

Comment: Yes, I did choose to build the tags manually just to learn how it would work; but perhaps it would be ideal to switch it over to a gem...